# Noindent footnote and nosubscript

Tags: numbering, footnotes, indentation

[image: The \quote is a bit offset.]

Attached above is my current example. Attatched below is my desired output. I want to ask on how to make the footnote numbers on the bottom of the page not like superscripts but like normal text and have a quad distance to the paragraph, which is unindented?

[image: Those are footnotes, you know.]

Comment: That depends on the document class in use. Can you show a minimal working example with a single paragraph and one or two footnotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{2em}{0em}{\thefootnotemark\quad}

\newenvironment{fnquote}{\begin{quote}\itshape}{\end{quote}\vspace{-1em}} % I do not know if there is a specific command for the skip after the quote that would be better suited than putting in -1em 

\begin{document}
    \footnote[9]{footnote}
    \footnote[10]{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  
            \begin{fnquote}
                This is a fnquote.
            \end{fnquote}}
    \footnote[11]{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\end{document}
```

[image]